# How to demonstrate that this process is weakly stationary?

Tags: time-series, self-study

Given $X_t=\sin(2\pi Ut)$ with $U$ uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ and $t$ integer,
how can I prove that $X_t$ is weakly stationary? (I didn't manage to calculate the correlation because I didn't have the joint distribution of $(X_t,X_s)$.)
How can I prove that $X_t$ is not strictly stationary?

Comment: What have you tried? What definition of weakly stationary are you using? How would you go about applying it to $X_t$? When you do, where do you get stuck? Notice, too, that you *do* have enough information to compute the joint distribution of $X_s$ and $X_t$.

Comment: the definition of weak stationnarity of a process Xt is E(Xt)=constant, Var(Xt)=constant and cov(Xt,Xt+h) depends only on h.As I mentioned I could not calculate the covariance of (Xt,Xs) because I don't have the joint distribution of this two variables.

Comment: On the contrary, you have *full* information about this process, including the joint distribution of any pair of the variables.

Comment: Are you sure you have quoted your problem correctly? I suspect you meant to write $X_t = \sin(2\pi(U+t))$, which *is* weakly stationary, instead of  $X_t = \sin(2\pi(Ut))$, which is not even first-order stationary.

Comment: Ah yes you are right I verified, it is sin(2πUt). But, I didn't see how it is weakly stationnary could you explain to me please

Comment: You provided a definition of weak stationarity in terms of expectations, so go ahead and compute them! What results do you get? To get you started, I find $\mathbb{E}(\sin(2\pi Ut))$ = $\int_0^1\sin(2\pi ut)du$ = $\sin(\pi t)^2/(\pi t),$ which varies with $t$ (and therefore is not stationary), whereas $\mathbb{E}(\sin(2\pi(U+t)))=0,$ which does not vary with $t$ (showing this particular process is at least first-order stationary).

Comment: I am sure that Xt is defined like sin(2πUt). What you said E(sin(2πUt)) = sin(πt)2/(πt) is true. But with t =1,2,.. and t is finite wich is the case in my exersice I will have sin(π)=sin(2π)=...sin(kπ)=0 that is E(sin(2πUt))=0. I just could not calculate the covariance for Xt.

Comment: This is the first time you have mentioned that $t$ must be integral: please edit your question to include this *crucial* restriction!  Computing the covariance is no different: apply the definitions and calculate the integrals they call for.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\mathbb E(X_tX_{t+s})=\int_0^1\sin(2\pi ut)\sin(2\pi u(t+s))\mathrm du,$$
and 
$$2\sin a\sin b=\cos(a-b)+\cos(a+b)$$
gives a simplification of the integral.

The process is not strictly stationary, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516779/is-sin-omega-n-n-geq-1-a-strictly-stationary-process).